# How should I make this code to display inline

Tags: html, css

How should I make the ul to display inline. I need  a css that can display the list inline in header navigation of my website

```
<div id="sidebar2" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="widget login_widget">
        <h3>My Account</h3>
        <ul class="xoxo blogroll" style="color: red;">
            <li>
                <a href="http://listing.entranceuniversity.com/author/jaysenoringmail-com/">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://listing.entranceuniversity.com/?ptype=profile">Edit Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://listing.entranceuniversity.com/?ptype=profile">Change Password</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://listing.entranceuniversity.com/author/jaysenoringmail-com/?list=favourite">My Favorites</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://listing.entranceuniversity.com/?ptype=post_listing">Add Listing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://listing.entranceuniversity.com/?ptype=login&amp;action=logout" class="signin">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is OP really asking to display the `li`s within the `ul` inline here? That's how I'm reading it (OP said they wanted to use it as a navbar)

Comment: yes its for the nav bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: inline` for your list items:

```
ul.xoxo li{display:inline;}
```

Also note that you need to remove `"` after `login_widget` inside `login_widget"=""` to make your HTML markup becomes valid.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2gaj/1/)**

Comment: .xoxo? Hugs and kisses?

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css style to your stylesheet

```
li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Make sure to use a `clear: both` after `ul`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, just add:

```
<style>
li {
display:inline;
}
</style>
```